# How to prevent warnings in ruby 2.7

Tags: ruby

In ruby 2.7 I having a lot of warnings like this:

```
<main>: warning: __FILE__ in eval may not return location in binding; use Binding#source_location instead
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pry-nav-0.3.0/lib/pry-nav.rb:17: 
warning: in `eval'
```

The RUBYOPT with such parameters doesn't work:

```
-W:no-deprecated -W:no-experimental
```

Comment: This is strictly related to the use of pry, no? If so, did you try updating to the last version of the gem (0.13.0)?

Comment: It used by pry-rails gem, currently, it points to 0.12.2

Comment: Try uninstalling both gems, then installing just pry-rails. It should install pry -v 0.13.0.

Comment: Also, I have pry-nav gem, and maybe more pry's, I think it's better to just prevent warnings

Comment: That's not a deprecation, nor an experimental warning. Maybe you can just use `-W0` (`ruby -W0 file.rb`).

Comment: @SebastianPalma what is the syntax to put it into RUBYOPT?

Comment: Try with `export RUBYOPT='-W0'`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This is pry specific and it should have been fixed, see [this commit](https://github.com/pry/pry/commit/272b3290b5250d28ee82a5ff65aa3b29b825e37b).

Update pry (which pry-rails has a dependency) to v0.13.0

Edit: On the other hand, pry-nav which also seems to be involved in your issues currently asks for something lower than v0.13.0, so it might not work just like this out of the box. You have to get it to run with the latest pry.